# Vue JS v-for generated components not extending site hight (overflow-y)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, loops, overflow, vue.js

I've made a little notes-app where users can add and edit notes. This notes-app is inside a sidebar which can be toggled (twitter bootstrap).

The problem is here, if a user adds more notes than can be displayed within the  hight of the side, the side isn't extending by making it scrollable. They are just displayed beyond the visible area of the page.

I've tested it with hard coded components, and those expand the side hight by making it scrollable. It's like the Vue generated components are not recognized.

**html**

```
<aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark" id="notes_sidebar">
                <div class="tab-content">

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <h2 class="control-sidebar-heading">
                            Your Notes
                        </h2>

                        <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">

                            <li>
                                <a @click="addNote()">
                                    <i class="menu-icon fa fa-plus bg-green"></i>
                                    <div class="menu-info">
                                        <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">New Note</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li v-for="note in notes" transition="fade">
                                <a @click="setActive($index)">
                                    <i class="menu-icon fa fa-sticky-note-o bg-yellow"></i>
                                    <div class="menu-info">
                                        <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">{?{ note.name }?}</h4>
                                        <p>{?{ note.date }?} <span class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x pull-right text-red" @click="deleteNote($index)"></span></p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>
...
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to make vue generated components overflow-y scrollable too?

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery to insert things into the sidebar, to see if it handles growing dynamically? Is there anything different about the structure  (say, an extra container) between what you tested that works and what Vue builds?

Comment: Just tried it with jQuery and with that it works fine (is overflow-y scrollable)..
No same structure, just copy/pasted the same elements and filled them manually..

Answer (score 0):

you could check if any of the containers have height limits.
I had a similar problem and then found I had 'max-height' on parent container.